# Xcode 4 build 4A2002a

Tags: xcode, ios

Does Xcode4 new version (build 4A2002a) is improved over its previous version? I am just thinking whether to download it or not, because i don't want to face with new bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's more stable than the previous one. See [XCode 4 (4A2002a) Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_4_and_ios_sdk_4.3__final/xcode_4_rn.pdf) for details.